# How to flatten a computed object without losing reactivity

Tags: vue.js, vuejs3, vue-composition-api

I'm using a computed object. I want to expose the properties of that object in the setup function, but I haven't found how.

```js
export default {
  setup() {
    const counter = Vue.ref(0)
    const data = Vue.computed(() => ({
      plus1: counter.value + 1,
      plus2: counter.value + 2,
    }))
    const increment = () => {
      counter.value++
    }
    
    return {
      counter,
      plus1: data.value.plus1, // This is bad, no reactivity
      plus2: data.value.plus2,
      increment
    }
  },
};
```

Full code pen here : https://codepen.io/philfontaine/pen/KKmzJrK

EDIT

Alternatives I have considered:

- Using the object data directly in the template
- Using a computed property of each of the properties

But these are *alternatives*, not how I really wished it could work.

Comment: out of curiosity, why not just use `data` in return and `data.plus1` in template? Otherwise, it seems to me, you'll need to create a `reactive` or individual refs for each key in `data`

Comment: Yes, I can definitely do that. But then that's not how I initially wanted to consume my data in the template, I would only be doing it this way because I can't do it the way I really want. I just felt that it's a limitation of the composition-api and was wondering if I was missing something of if it's simply not possible.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You cannot directly flatten a computed object (no API is currently provided to do that).

I ended up resorting to using the computed object directly in the template.

Answer (score 2):

You could use a `reactive` object with `toRef` instead.

```js
Vue.createApp({
  setup() {
    const counter = Vue.ref(0);

    const data = Vue.reactive({
      get plus1() { return counter.value + 1; },
      get plus2() { return counter.value + 2; },
    });

    const increment = () => counter.value++;

    return {
      counter,
      plus1: Vue.toRef(data, 'plus1'),
      plus2: Vue.toRef(data, 'plus2'),
      increment
    }
  }
}).mount('#app');
```

```css
#app {
  font-family: Avenir, Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;
  text-align: center;
  color: #2c3e50;
  margin-top: 60px;
}

a, button {
  color: #4fc08d;
}

button {
  background: none;
  border: solid 1px;
  border-radius: 2em;
  font: inherit;
  padding: 0.75em 2em;
  margin: 0.85em;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://unpkg.com/vue@next"></script>

<div id="app">
  <div>{{ counter }}</div>
  <div>{{ plus1 }}</div>
  <div>{{ plus2 }}</div>
  <button @click="increment">Increment</button>
</div>
```

Although, this is a little awkward to me. I would use some other method if possible; why do `plus1` and `plus2` need to be a part of the same object? What's wrong with

```js
const counter = ref(0);
const plus1 = computed(() => counter.value + 1);
const plus2 = computed(() => counter.value + 2);
```

this? I'm sure your real example is much more complex, but it may be worth thinking about: `computed` is the intuitive thing to use here, and on individual variables.

Comment: I'm not sure if getters in `reactive` work as intended. Can you confirm the framework explicitly supports this?

Comment: Thanks for this suggestion. Getters in a reactive object does seem to work, but it feels kind of weird/hackish. My real life example is that I have 4 variables that depend on 1 variable (kind of like a switch case on a string). I'd rather to this switch once and return the 4 variables than doing the switch 4 times in 4 different computed properties. I don't really need to flatten this object, but it would have been nicer. This to me feels like a limitation of the composition-api.

Comment: @Phil If the cases in your four switches are similar enough, you could try making the computed getters as one function that gets passed to four different `computed`s. If they're similar, but not the same, you could make those getters with a factory function. Something like `computed(makeSwitchStatement('someCondition'));`. Then you'll have one function and four `computed` calls. Just might work... 